# Lenovo BIOS setting using PowerShell

Tags: bios, powershell, lenovo-desktop-computer

I am trying to change BIOS settings through PowerShell.  When I run the below command line, it runs successfully, but when I reboot the PC I see no change in the BIOS settings.

the command line:

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class Lenovo_SetBiosSetting -Namespace root\wmi -ComputerName computername -ErrorAction Stop).SetBiosSetting("After Power Loss,Power Off")
```

The output:

```
__GENUS          : 2                 
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS      
__SUPERCLASS     :                   
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS      
__RELPATH        :                   
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 1                 
__DERIVATION     : {}                
__SERVER         :                   
__NAMESPACE      :                   
__PATH           :                   
return           : Success           
PSComputerName   :
```

Do I need to save the change after running the first command?

Comment: You do have a `Lenovo` machine? [You are better of using `(gwmi -class Lenovo_SetBiosSetting -namespace root\wmi).SetBiosSetting("After Power Loss,Power Off")`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017986/wmic-how-to-use-lenovo-setbiossetting-method).  You also have to save the changes [`(Get-WmiObject -Class Lenovo_SaveBiosSettings -Namespace root\wmi -ComputerName computername -ErrorAction Stop).SaveBiosSettings("password,ascii,us")`](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/2e0x97/trying_to_powershellise_a_vbs_script_lenovo/)

Comment: @Ramhound this is not a valid syntax for my BIOS version. in your example the command line should be: `(Get-WmiObject -Class Lenovo_SetBiosSetting -Namespace root\wmi -ComputerName computername -ErrorAction Stop).SetBiosSetting("After Power Loss,Power Off")`

Comment: Which command are you saying is incorrect?  Does not matter you have to save the changes.  Disregard the first half of my comment

Comment: your new command is good. do I need password to save bios setting?

Comment: How am I suppose to know if you need a password to save your machine's BIOS settings?  `(gwmi -class Lenovo_SaveBiosSettings -namespace root\wmi).
SaveBiosSettings()` pure the documentation by Lenovo

Comment: @Ramhound post an answer!

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - *The solution to the author's problem was already submitted.*

Comment: @fixer1234 The question was for Lenovo M93p, the same apply for Lenovo Flex20 and M93p Tiny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Ramhound suggestion, I had to run one command line to save the new change :

```
(gwmi -class Lenovo_SaveBiosSettings -namespace root\wmi).SaveBiosSettings()
```

or (If your BIOS is password protected):

```
(gwmi -class Lenovo_SaveBiosSettings -namespace root\wmi).SaveBiosSettings("Password,Encoding,KbdLang;")
```

Thank you