# What can a file copy miss that an image backup of a disk (image) will definitely catch, and is there anything that they both can miss?

Tags: backup, disk-image, copy

So here is what I can think of that a file copy can miss:

- Locked Files (but you’ll usually know)
- Partitions
- Boot Flags on a partition

Is there anything that both of them will miss?

- bios settings
- board jumper settings
- Settings on a Card

  - For instance an additional hdd controller might have a separate bios program of its own with settings for RAID 0, 1, 5, 10 etc...

Comment: You would seriously need to ask yourself why any of the settings you written down as missed would require a backup in the first place.

Comment: @LPChip Because the settings match and yet the functionality does not, which is why I’m looking for alternatives.

Comment: The OS can ask the bios what a setting is, but it is up to the BIOS to provide it. Although it is possible to retrieve the settings, it definitely can't restore them, so there is no point in backing them up. Jumpers are hardware, so cannot be changed, settings on a Card use another BIOS, same as above. A bios can be flashed, but every bios requires very specific access. It is simply impossible to incorporate code for every single BIOS out there.

Comment: @LPChip - it isn't true that OS *"definitely can't restore"* BIOS settings.  I can set BIOS using [gwmi](https://superuser.com/questions/1019902/lenovo-bios-setting-using-powershell) on my Thinkpad for example.  It isn't generic but it is certainly possible on some machines.

Comment: @lx07 yes you need a thirdparty tool. There is no backup solution available that can make a system image and include the BIOS in there. That was my point.

Comment: @LPChip , lx07 I am just try to ensure I’ve taken everything into account.  I’m working on a system that encompasses a Windows CE POS, and a Windows server, the issue is coming into play at a POS, and just wanted to make sure I had accounted for everything.